# Order of equation that is used to get the matrix for calculating eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

My professor in class has taught this equation as being $det(\lambda I - A)$ mostly with regards to finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of liner transformations but I have seen it online as $det(A - \lambda I)$. Does the order matter in these cases? I tried to google this but I couldn't find anything

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter. Recall that multiplying a single row (or equivalently, column) of a matrix $M$ by a scalar $a$ multiplies the determinant by $a$. Note also that $\lambda I - A = (-1)(A - \lambda I)$ is the result of multiplying all rows (or columns) by $-1$. Therefore we have,
$$\det (A - \lambda I) = (-1)^n\det(\lambda I - A)$$
where $n$ is the number of rows/columns.

So, we therefore have
\begin{align*}
&\det (A - \lambda I) = 0 \\
\iff \, &(-1)^n\det(\lambda I - A) = 0 \\
\iff \, &\det(\lambda I - A) = 0.
\end{align*}

Comment: Ah ok this is what I expected conceptually but wasn't 100% sure of. Thanks a bunch